Graphic options stop working when displaying multiple contourplots
I want to show multiple contourplots next to each other as shown in the following picture:

I tried the following code:

MyContourPlot = ListContourPlot[{data1, data2, data3 }, PlotLayout-> "Row", Frame->True, FrameStyle -> Black, FrameLabel->{{"y in 10um", ""},{"x in 10 um"," Bx dann By dann Bz (gemessen)"}}, ColorFunction->"CandyColors"]

Which gives me the following output:

However, I want the Frame to be black and not grey, and I want the top label to be above the individual plots. How could I do this?

The frame is black not grey.

The Frame is a bit on the grey side.  (Same thing for the axis labels and tick labels.)  Try adding FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick] to see the difference.

I cannot reproduce your result. What is your MMA version? How about putting sample data, too?

@JimB your suggestion worked, I think it was black from the beginning just as azerbajdzan said but it wasn't really visible and also the ticks were grey which made it appear grey alltogether, thank you

I have always found the default text and lines in Mathematica to be a bit more grey than black so I typically specify Black explicitly.

@JimB I understand, I will do the same for sure. While we are at it, do you know how to make the numbers on the x axis also black? I tried some AxesStyle->Black but it didn't work

Once you use Frame you need to use options starting with Frame such as FrameStyle, FrameTicks, and FrameTicksStyle.

Perhaps you could separately plot three graphs, and then combine them into a single figure.
data1 = Table[x  y, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}];
data2 = Table[y^2, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}];
data3 = Table[x^2, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}];
padding1 = {{40, 10}, {20, 20}};
padding2 = {{20, 0}, {50, 20}};
padding3 = {{20, 0}, {20, 20}};
imSize = 100;
p1 = ListContourPlot[data1, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y in 10um"}, {, " Bx"}}, 
   ColorFunction -> "CandyColors", ImagePadding -> padding1, 
   ImageSize -> Automatic -> imSize, BaselinePosition -> Axis];
p2 = ListContourPlot[data2, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
   FrameLabel -> {{}, {"x in 10 um", " By"}}, 
   ColorFunction -> "CandyColors", ImagePadding -> padding2, 
   ImageSize -> Automatic -> imSize, BaselinePosition -> Axis];
p3 = ListContourPlot[data3, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
   FrameLabel -> {{}, {, " Bz"}}, ColorFunction -> "CandyColors", 
   ImagePadding -> padding3, ImageSize -> Automatic -> imSize, 
   BaselinePosition -> Axis];
Grid[{{p1, p2, p3}}]


